# adjective to describe someone who "loves life"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective to describe someone who "love life" meaning they love the very fact of being alive, are excited to experience the possibilities of living.

I'm not talking about people loving THEIR personal lives (so words such as *happy* or *fulfilled* wouldn't work here) but rather loving life in itself.

This word may be used in a sentence like: " I wish I could be like John he really is a (...) person"

Comment: I'd like to say that they are a *vitaphile*. Unfortunately, that word doesn't exist . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two terms that come to mind are "[bon vivant](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bon-vivant?s=t)" and "[epicure](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/epicure?s=t)."  Another term, though it can have a negative connotation for doing it to excess, is "[hedonist](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hedonist?s=t)," though actual hedonists seem to embrace the term.  A fourth term that comes to mind is "[voluptuary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/voluptuary)."

Anyway, for me, the French say it best with "bon vivant," and they even have the best term for that certain *je ne sais quoi* that a bon vivant possesses: "[joie de vivre](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/joie-de-vivre?s=t)."

By the way, these are loanwords in English, meaning that they're adopted into English from a foreign language, French in this case, with little or no modification, so being adopted into English, they are perfectly acceptable English terms.  You can find them in any English dictionary, and they are generally understood by English speakers.

Comment: "If you came this way in may time, you would find the hedges 
White again, in May, with voluptuary sweetness. "  -[Little Gidding](http://www.columbia.edu/itc/history/winter/w3206/edit/tseliotlittlegidding.html)

Answer (score 1):

*[Bon vivant](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bon-vivant?s=t)* is the closest term I can think of offhand.  Literally it means "a person fond of good living".  Removing the *bon* ("good") one could use:

- *vivant*

as "a person who enjoys life".

Answer (score 1):

Consider the ad-hoc adjective **life-loving**. It's simple and yet exactly what you're looking for:

> I wish I could be like John. He really is a **life-loving** person.